# Use a variable outside anonymous function

Tags: jquery, function, height, width

I tried all the solutions which I found here but none works for me..

```
var img = $("#img");
var width, height;
$("<img/>")
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        width = this.width;
        height = this.height;
                alert(width + "*" + height) ; // works
    });
alert(width + "*" + height) ; // undifined*undifined !! :(
```

As you can see, I need to use the height & width outside...

I REPEAT : I TRIED ABOUT 6-7 SOLUTIONS FROM StackOverFlow!
Maybe I havn't done them well... anyway, they didn't work.

what should I do ?
Tnx.

Comment: The solution is: don't use `height` and `width` outside the callback. All uses of the variables should go inside the `load` callback function, which might not fire for several seconds. If you have some code that needs to use `height` and `width`, put *all* of that code inside the callback. If you can't put your code inside the callback, please **provide more context** to explain exactly why you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object into your anonymous callback function and set properties within the callback that will be 'seen' outside it:

```
var img = $("#img");
var dimensions = { width: 0, height: 0 };

$("<img/>")
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function(dimensions) {
        dimensions.width = this.width;
        dimensions.height = this.height;
        alert(dimensions.width + "*" + dimensions.height);
});

// Some time later, after callback has definitely fired...
alert(dimensions.width + "*" + dimensions.height);
```

But as @apsillers comments, the second alert won't work as is because it gets executed *before* your anonymous function ever gets called. Remember, all jQuery's `load()` function is doing is accepting an anonymous *function definition* as its argument and remembering it for later. It's entirely down to jQuery if and when it ever calls that function.

Comment: For the OP's benefit: an example of "some time later" might be in an event handler, like a `click` listener that needs to use the dimensions.

Comment: Did this answer help? If so, feel free to mark it as correct :)